# Looking for science fiction assassination story with mysterious girl

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

For years I've been looking for a short science fiction story about a man who was released from a prison planet in order to assassinate a candidate for galactic president. He does this on a space station, and escapes with the help of a mysterious and very attractive girl with silvery hair and multi-colored skin.

I read this short story some 5-6 years ago online.

The assassin was released from the prison planet by some influential people so that he may assassinate the galactic president candidate, whose rule would, according to said people, be bad for the galaxy.

I also remember that the girl, who is actually a young woman is also a prostitute. The first time he sees her she's walking into the bar accompanied by another man. I don't remember why she helps him. She was likely his contact, given to him by those who sent him on the assassination.

They escape together after creating a diversion with an explosion, running off into some corridor that probably leads to a way off the space station.

The story story ends there but in my opinion leaves room for a sequel, even if only to explore the protagonists' developing relationship.

Comment: Are you sure it was a short story? Could it have been an excerpt from a longer story? Also do you remember if you read it in a magazine, book or online?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it was a short story, not part of a longer story. Although, as I said, it asks for a continuation. So I am not 100% sure. I read it online.

Comment: Novels are often serialized in magazines.

Comment: Hello @Dovid, I've set a bounty on your question. If you remember [any additional details](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561), now would be a good time to [edit] them in.

Comment: Hello @Moacir and thanks for trying to help me find this story. I looked up the index of that issue here (https://archive.org/details/sim_analog-science-fiction-fact_1983_103_index/mode/2up), but couldn't find a story by that author or by that name in 1983. Moreover, I found no place where a story by that name is attributed to that author.

Comment: Aspects remind me of Spinrad's "Agent of Chaos".   But that was a full novel and not a short story.

Comment: Sounds like Jupiter Ascending (https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1617661).

Comment: Jupiter Ascending? Which is a 2015 film, and not a short story I read somewhere in the early 2000s. I saw that film, and never even noticed any common plot elements. Sorry.